# sql running total for an account balance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I am trying to prepare a subsidiary ledger view report in SQL2008.
Here is the temp table

```
AccountCode |Date       |Fiche Type      |Debit    |Credit  |Balance
100.001.001 |1.1.2015   |Açılış Fişi     |1856,09  |0       |1856,09
100.001.002 |1.1.2015   |Mahsup Fişi     |0        |20      |-20
100.001.001 |1.2.2015   |Tediye Fişi     |0        |950     |906,09
100.001.002 |1.2.2015   |Açılış Fişi     |2931,37  |0       |2911,37
100.001.001 |1.4.2015   |Mahsup Fişi     |0        |6,25    |899,84
100.001.002 |1.6.2015   |Tahsil Fişi     |0        |400     |2511,37
100.002.001 |1.7.2015   |Açılış Fişi     |0        |1969,5  |-1969,5
100.002.001 |1.20.2015  |Mahsup Fişi     |217,6    |0       |-1751,9
100.001.001 |1.21.2015  |Mahsup Fişi     |500      |0       |1399,84
100.002.001 |1.21.2015  |Tediye Fişi     |2000     |0       |248,1
100.001.002 |1.21.2015  |Tahsil Fişi     |543,34   |0       |3054,7
```

In the last column I am trying to calculate the balance for the accountcode in the first column. The formula for balance field is simply (Debit-Credit). Report should order by date. So for example in the 3rd row, since the account codes are the same, the balance field must take the first columns values and combine them with the 3rd columns' values (Row1(Debit-Credit)+Row3(Debit-Credit)).

I tried many things but no luck since the list is not ordered by the criteria which the running total based on.

Can anyone offer me a solution?

Comment: could you show your query ?

Comment: I tried many, this is one of them: `SELECT tmu.Accountcode, tmu.date, tmu.[Fiche Type], tmu.debit, tmu.credit, ( SELECT SUM(balance) from tempMuavin mua WHERE convert(char(10),tmu.Tarih,101)=convert(char(10),mua.tarih,101)) FROM tempMuavin tmu ORDER BY date` It produced a column with some strange values like: 4,36557456851006E-11 -5,18980414199177E-11 -7,82165443524718E-11 –

Answer (score 2):

```
    with x as 
    (
      select *,row_number() over (partition by accountcode order by date) sr 
      from ledger

    )
    select 
      (select sum(debit-credit) from x y where y.accountcode=x.accountcode and y.sr<x.sr) opening
      ,*
      ,(select sum(debit-credit) from x y where y.accountcode=x.accountcode and y.sr<=x.sr) closing
    from x
```

see on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8561/5)

HTH

Comment: This produced 3 additional columns below;

 |Opening     |Closing                              |SrNo
    |NULL        |-9,09640220925212E-08      |1

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use cumulative sum for this.  In SQL Server 2008, you can use a correlated subquery, join, or apply.  Here is the latter:

```
select l.*, cume.balance
from ledger l cross apply
     (select sum(debit - credit) as balance
      from ledger l2
      where l2.AccountCode = l.AccountCode and
            l2.date <= l.date
     ) cume;
```

Comment: I tried this, it gave me the total sum of the specific account.

Comment: @OrkunAntmen . . . At first, I could not figure out how that could be.  But, the `where` condition was `l2.date <= date` rather than `l2.date <= l.date` (now fixed).  The first version was a tautology, interpreted as `l2.date <= l2.date`, because of scoping rules.  Always qualify columns.

Comment: I think you are almost there Gordon.

I got the table below:

[link](http://rehband.com.tr/Clipboard01222.jpg)

I think I can try adding a logicalref(primary key) criteria from the fiche line table, because it automatically adds the total for the day which is very much logical for the query.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Or it is better to add a primary key column to the temp table as Mitan suggested and include this column in you Where clause.